# Handlebar js list construction

Tags: handlebars.js

For the following handlebar html

```
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li>{{#orderedList arrayItems}}{{this}}{{/list}}</li>
</ul>
```

I need output like this

```
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li>Hi</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to use list/each and convert the list to ordered list
But it need to be wrapped between ul  and li.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is `Language`? What is `#orderedList`?

Comment: Language is the array. Orderlist is a custom helper function to generate the output. @76484

Comment: Are you replacing the `orderedList` helper? Why does the `#each` need to happen _inside_ of the `<li>`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @76484

If i render that part of each outside li as a html it doesnt look good. thats why..

Comment: I won't be able to help you because I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish and what your data is. I hope someone else is able to help.

Comment: @76484 Wrote a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818898/remove-extra-li-inside-of-ul-in-handlebarjs With better clarity.