# Remove extra li inside of ul in handlebarjs

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a handlebar html

`<ul><li>{{#listConstruct product}}{{this}}{{/listConstruct}}</li></ul>`

Need to have output like this

```
<ul>
<li>Pen</li>
<li>Pencil</li>
<li>Notebook</li>
</ul>
```

I wrote a listConstruct helper like this.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('listConstruct', function(items) {
   let res = '';
    items.forEach((val)=>{res+= '<li>'+val+'</li>'});
   return res;
 });
```

But this result in output like this

`<ul><li><li>Pen</li><li>Pencil</li><li>Notebook</li></li></ul>`

How to remove the extra li inside of UL.

Comment: Can you post what `items` looks like?

Comment: It looks like you should just use a simple `#each`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0L7jf9dm/

Comment: @76484 Is it possible to achieve the same inside of li, rather than having having each between ul and li.

I need to render that handle bar template in HTML which look like this https://imgur.com/a/TEzd9Ku

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How would a list go _inside_ of an `<li>`? I don't understand why you want to put the `#each` inside of the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *truly* do not understand why you cannot use a simple `#each` as in:

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

If you absolutely must add your template *within* the `<li>`, then you can do the following. You can achieve your desired result by joining all of the items in your array together with `</li><li>` so that the finished string looks like `Pen</li><li>Pencil</li><li>Notebook`. This string, once injected into the template's `<li>` will produce your desired, valid HTML. Note: You will need to use Handlebars' [SafeString](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/utilities.html#handlebars-safestring-string) utility function so as not to escape the HTML tags in the helper's return value.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`<ul><li>{{#listConstruct product}}{{this}}{{/listConstruct}}</li></ul>`);

const product = [
  'Pen',
  'Pencil',
  'Notebook'
];

Handlebars.registerHelper('listConstruct', function (items, options) {
  return options.fn(new Handlebars.SafeString(items.join('</li><li>')));
});

document.body.innerHTML = template({ product });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```